# error 500 usando ajax en para recibir un json en django

Tags: ajax, json, django, error500

Estoy trabajando con Django y recibo un error 500, a una petición con Ajax. Tengo un modelo "Item",  al que he convertido a diccionario, y creado una funcion toJson(), que debe permitirme  obtener todo el objeto en un input, para hacer un select, para esto empleo como dije Ajax con una petición POST, , pero en vez de eso viene vacio.
Se que el error tiene que ver con la composicion del JSON que construyo porque con postman he visto que hay un problema con los indices, porque este es el error que tira: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Muestro el modelo, el ajax y la vista

"MODELO"

`````
    class Item(models.Model): 
        operation = models.ForeignKey(Operation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubcategoryItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        categ = models.ForeignKey(CategItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        item_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='item')
        item_description = models.TextField(null=True)
        item_SKU = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=True)
        ean = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
        is_active = models.BooleanField()
        price = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
        purchase_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
        tax = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
        color = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
        size = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)
        weight = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
        height = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    
        image = models.ImageField(
            upload_to='backoffice/static/images',
            blank=True,
            null=True
        )
        image_1 = models.ImageField(
            upload_to='backoffice/static/images',
            blank=True,
            null=True
        )
        image_2 = models.ImageField(
            upload_to='backoffice/static/images',
            blank=True,
            null=True
        )
        image_3 = models.ImageField(
            upload_to='backoffice/static/images',
            blank=True,
            null=True
        )
        image_4 = models.ImageField(
            upload_to='backoffice/static/images',
            blank=True,
            null=True
        )
        image_5 = models.ImageField(
            upload_to='backoffice/static/images',
            blank=True,
            null=True
        )
    
        class Meta:
            ordering = ('item_name',)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.item_name
    
        def toJSON(self):
            item = model_to_dict(self)
            item['image'] = self.get_image()
            item['image_1'] = self.get_image()
            item['image_2'] = self.get_image()
            item['image_3'] = self.get_image()
            item['image_4'] = self.get_image()
            item['image_5'] = self.get_image()
            item['operation'] = self.operation.toJSON()
            item['brand'] = self.brand.toJSON()
            item['subcategory'] = self.subcategory.toJSON()
            item['categ'] = self.categ.toJSON()
            item['section'] = self.section.toJSON()
            item['price'] = format(self.price, '.2f')
            item['purchase_price'] = format(self.purchase_price, '.2f')
            item['tax'] = format(self.tax, '.2f')
            return item
        
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('all_items.html', kwargs={'pk':self.id})
    ```
    
    "View"
    ```
    class SoldCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
        model = Sold
        form_class = SoldForm
        template_name = 'solds/add_invoice.html'
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['tittle'] = 'Sold Forms'
            context['table_tittle'] = 'New sold'
            context['table_subtittle'] = 'Add here your new solds'
            return context
        
        @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
        def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        
        @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
        def post(self, request, *args,**kwargs):
            data={}
            try:
                action = request.POST['action']
                if action == 'search_item':
                    
                    data=[]
                    prods = Item.objects.filter(item_name=request.POST['term'])
                    
                    
                    for i in prods:
                        item = i.toJSON()
                        item['value'] = i.item_name
                        data.append(item)
                        #data.append(i.toJSON())
    
                else:
                    data['error']='no ha ingresado una opcion'
            except Exception as e:
                data['error'] = str(e)
        
            return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
            
        def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse('all_sold') ```
    
    "Ajax"
    ````
    $('input[name="search_box"s]').autocomplete({
        source:function(request, response){
            alert(request.term);
    
            $.ajax({
                url:window.location.pathname,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'action':'search_item',
                    'term': request.term
                },
                dataType:'json',
            }).done(function(data){
                response(data);
                console.log(data);
            }).fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus, errorTrown){
                alert(errorTrown);
            }).always(function(data){
    
            });
    
        },
        delay: 500,
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, ui){
            console.log(ui.item); 
    
        }
    });
`````

"traceback"

```
TypeError at /dashboard/backoffice/new_sold
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/backoffice/new_sold
Django Version: 3.1.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
Exception Location: /Users/blackmaster/Documents/programacion/proyectos_django/localsys/backoffice/views/sold.py, line 73, in post
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.9
Python Path:    
['/Users/blackmaster/Documents/programacion/proyectos_django/localsys',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 01 Apr 2021 21:05:59 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py, line 76, in __getitem__
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """
        Return the last data value for this key, or [] if it's an empty list;
        raise KeyError if not found.
        """
        try:
            list_ = super().__getitem__(key) …
        except KeyError:
            raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
        try:
            return list_[-1]
        except IndexError:
            return []
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
__class__   
<class 'django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDict'>
key 
'term'
self    
<QueryDict: {'action': ['search_item']}>
During handling of the above exception ('term'), another exception occurred:
/Users/blackmaster/Documents/programacion/proyectos_django/localsys/backoffice/views/sold.py, line 61, in post
    def post(self, request, *args,**kwargs):
        data={}
        try:
            action = request.POST['action']
            if action == 'search_item':
                
                data=[]
                prods = Item.objects.filter(item_name=request.POST['term']) …
                
                
                for i in prods:
                   # item = i.toJSON()
                    item['value'] = i.item_name
                    data.append(item)
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
action  
'search_item'
args    
()
data    
[]
kwargs  
{}
request 
<WSGIRequest: POST '/dashboard/backoffice/new_sold'>
self    
<backoffice.views.sold.SoldCreate object at 0x7fd6068a8c90>
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py, line 78, in __getitem__
        """
        Return the last data value for this key, or [] if it's an empty list;
        raise KeyError if not found.
        """
        try:
            list_ = super().__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key) …
        try:
            return list_[-1]
        except IndexError:
            return []
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
__class__   
<class 'django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDict'>
key 
'term'
self    
<QueryDict: {'action': ['search_item']}>
During handling of the above exception ('term'), another exception occurred:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = await sync_to_async(response_for_exception)(request, exc)
            return response
        return inner
    else:
        @wraps(get_response)
        def inner(request):
            try:
                response = get_response(request) …
            except Exception as exc:
                response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
            return response
        return inner
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
exc 
TypeError('list indices must be integers or slices, not str')
get_response    
<bound method BaseHandler._get_response of <django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler object at 0x7fd60504df10>>
request 
<WSGIRequest: POST '/dashboard/backoffice/new_sold'>
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 179, in _get_response
        if response is None:
            wrapped_callback = self.make_view_atomic(callback)
            # If it is an asynchronous view, run it in a subthread.
            if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(wrapped_callback):
                wrapped_callback = async_to_sync(wrapped_callback)
            try:
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
            except Exception as e:
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
                if response is None:
                    raise
        # Complain if the view returned None (a common error).
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
callback    
<function SoldCreate at 0x7fd6065acf80>
callback_args   
()
callback_kwargs 
{}
middleware_method   
<bound method CsrfViewMiddleware.process_view of <django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware object at 0x7fd6066e56d0>>
request 
<WSGIRequest: POST '/dashboard/backoffice/new_sold'>
response    
None
self    
<django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler object at 0x7fd60504df10>
wrapped_callback    
<function SoldCreate at 0x7fd6065acf80>
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py, line 70, in view
            self = cls(**initkwargs)
            self.setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
            if not hasattr(self, 'request'):
                raise AttributeError(
                    "%s instance has no 'request' attribute. Did you override "
                    "setup() and forget to call super()?" % cls.__name__
                )
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) …
        view.view_class = cls
        view.view_initkwargs = initkwargs
        # take name and docstring from class
        update_wrapper(view, cls, updated=())
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
args    
()
cls 
<class 'backoffice.views.sold.SoldCreate'>
initkwargs  
{}
kwargs  
{}
request 
<WSGIRequest: POST '/dashboard/backoffice/new_sold'>
self    
<backoffice.views.sold.SoldCreate object at 0x7fd6068a8c90>
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py, line 43, in _wrapper
        # bound_method has the signature that 'decorator' expects i.e. no
        # 'self' argument, but it's a closure over self so it can call
        # 'func'. Also, wrap method.__get__() in a function because new
        # attributes can't be set on bound method objects, only on functions.
        bound_method = partial(method.__get__(self, type(self)))
        for dec in decorators:
            bound_method = dec(bound_method)
        return bound_method(*args, **kwargs) …
    # Copy any attributes that a decorator adds to the function it decorates.
    for dec in decorators:
        _update_method_wrapper(_wrapper, dec)
    # Preserve any existing attributes of 'method', including the name.
    update_wrapper(_wrapper, method)
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
args    
(<WSGIRequest: POST '/dashboard/backoffice/new_sold'>,)
bound_method    
<function csrf_exempt.<locals>.wrapped_view at 0x7fd606acba70>
dec 
<function csrf_exempt at 0x7fd605232a70>
decorators  
[<function csrf_exempt at 0x7fd605232a70>]
kwargs  
{}
method  
<function SoldCreate.dispatch at 0x7fd605d26440>
self    
<backoffice.views.sold.SoldCreate object at 0x7fd6068a8c90>
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py, line 54, in wrapped_view
def csrf_exempt(view_func):
    """Mark a view function as being exempt from the CSRF view protection."""
    # view_func.csrf_exempt = True would also work, but decorators are nicer
    # if they don't have side effects, so return a new function.
    def wrapped_view(*args, **kwargs):
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs) …
    wrapped_view.csrf_exempt = True
    return wraps(view_func)(wrapped_view)
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
args    
(<WSGIRequest: POST '/dashboard/backoffice/new_sold'>,)
kwargs  
{}
view_func   
functools.partial(<bound method SoldCreate.dispatch of <backoffice.views.sold.SoldCreate object at 0x7fd6068a8c90>>)
/Users/blackmaster/Documents/programacion/proyectos_django/localsys/backoffice/views/sold.py, line 51, in dispatch
        context['tittle'] = 'Sold Forms'
        context['table_tittle'] = 'New sold'
        context['table_subtittle'] = 'Add here your new solds'
        return context
    
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs) …
    
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def post(self, request, *args,**kwargs):
        data={}
        try:
            action = request.POST['action']
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
__class__   
<class 'backoffice.views.sold.SoldCreate'>
args    
(<WSGIRequest: POST '/dashboard/backoffice/new_sold'>,)
kwargs  
{}
self    
<backoffice.views.sold.SoldCreate object at 0x7fd6068a8c90>
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py, line 52, in dispatch
class LoginRequiredMixin(AccessMixin):
    """Verify that the current user is authenticated."""
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return self.handle_no_permission()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) …
class PermissionRequiredMixin(AccessMixin):
    """Verify that the current user has all specified permissions."""
    permission_required = None
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
__class__   
<class 'django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin'>
args    
()
kwargs  
{}
request 
<WSGIRequest: POST '/dashboard/backoffice/new_sold'>
self    
<backoffice.views.sold.SoldCreate object at 0x7fd6068a8c90>
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py, line 98, in dispatch
        # Try to dispatch to the right method; if a method doesn't exist,
        # defer to the error handler. Also defer to the error handler if the
        # request method isn't on the approved list.
        if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
            handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
        else:
            handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) …
    def http_method_not_allowed(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.warning(
            'Method Not Allowed (%s): %s', request.method, request.path,
            extra={'status_code': 405, 'request': request}
        )
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
args    
()
handler 
<bound method SoldCreate.post of <backoffice.views.sold.SoldCreate object at 0x7fd6068a8c90>>
kwargs  
{}
request 
<WSGIRequest: POST '/dashboard/backoffice/new_sold'>
self    
<backoffice.views.sold.SoldCreate object at 0x7fd6068a8c90>
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py, line 43, in _wrapper
        # bound_method has the signature that 'decorator' expects i.e. no
        # 'self' argument, but it's a closure over self so it can call
        # 'func'. Also, wrap method.__get__() in a function because new
        # attributes can't be set on bound method objects, only on functions.
        bound_method = partial(method.__get__(self, type(self)))
        for dec in decorators:
            bound_method = dec(bound_method)
        return bound_method(*args, **kwargs) …
    # Copy any attributes that a decorator adds to the function it decorates.
    for dec in decorators:
        _update_method_wrapper(_wrapper, dec)
    # Preserve any existing attributes of 'method', including the name.
    update_wrapper(_wrapper, method)
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
args    
(<WSGIRequest: POST '/dashboard/backoffice/new_sold'>,)
bound_method    
<function csrf_exempt.<locals>.wrapped_view at 0x7fd606acb9e0>
dec 
<function csrf_exempt at 0x7fd605232a70>
decorators  
[<function csrf_exempt at 0x7fd605232a70>]
kwargs  
{}
method  
<function SoldCreate.post at 0x7fd605d265f0>
self    
<backoffice.views.sold.SoldCreate object at 0x7fd6068a8c90>
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py, line 54, in wrapped_view
def csrf_exempt(view_func):
    """Mark a view function as being exempt from the CSRF view protection."""
    # view_func.csrf_exempt = True would also work, but decorators are nicer
    # if they don't have side effects, so return a new function.
    def wrapped_view(*args, **kwargs):
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs) …
    wrapped_view.csrf_exempt = True
    return wraps(view_func)(wrapped_view)
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
args    
(<WSGIRequest: POST '/dashboard/backoffice/new_sold'>,)
kwargs  
{}
view_func   
functools.partial(<bound method SoldCreate.post of <backoffice.views.sold.SoldCreate object at 0x7fd6068a8c90>>)
/Users/blackmaster/Documents/programacion/proyectos_django/localsys/backoffice/views/sold.py, line 73, in post
                    item['value'] = i.item_name
                    data.append(item)
                    #data.append(i.toJSON())
            else:
                data['error']='no ha ingresado una opcion'
        except Exception as e:
            data['error'] = str(e) …
    
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
        
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('all_sold')
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
action  
'search_item'
args    
()
data    
[]
kwargs  
{}
request 
<WSGIRequest: POST '/dashboard/backoffice/new_sold'>
self    
<backoffice.views.sold.SoldCreate object at 0x7fd6068a8c90>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primero te recomendaría que pongas una captura o el stacktrace completo del error para ver en que linea de código tiro el error, también te sugeriría que imprimas el toJSON() para que veas si se esta formando bien el json de tu objeto, de lo que pude observar en tu código creo que el error debe de estar por acá:

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
def post(self, request, *args,**kwargs):
    data={}
    try:
        action = request.POST['action']
        if action == 'search_item':
            
            data=[]
            prods = Item.objects.filter(item_name=request.POST['term'])
            
            for i in prods:
                item = i.toJSON()
                item['value'] = i.item_name
                data.append(item)
                #data.append(i.toJSON())

        else:
            data['error']='no ha ingresado una opcion'
    except Exception as e:
        data['error'] = str(e)

    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Primero estas definiendo data como un diccionario y después como una lista, lo primero que corregiría seria esa parte ya que si tienes a data como lista y haces data['algo'] te va a dar error ya que una lista se maneja por índices no por keys, dices que quieres las opciones para un select, lo haría de esta manera para solucionar esto que te comento arriba:

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
def post(self, request, *args,**kwargs):
    data = dict()
    items=[]
    action = request.POST.get('action', None)

    if action:
        if action == 'search_item':
            
            prods = Item.objects.filter(item_name=request.POST.get('term', None)) # Con get, si se tiene el key 'term' se obtiene su valor, si no se tiene entonces se asigna None por defecto a 'term'
            
            for i in prods:
                item = i.toJSON()
                item['value'] = i.item_name
                items.append(item)
     else:
        data['error']='no ha ingresado una opcion'

     data['options'] = items 

    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False) # al final obtendras {'options': []} o {'error': 'no ha ingresado una opcion', 'options': []}
```

Si subes el stacktrace para ver en que linea dio el error, corrijo mi respuesta.

Saludos

Comment: lo acabo de añadir a al pregunta inicial, lo siento debi añadirlos inicialmente. gracias

Comment: Gracias, si pudieras probar lo que te mencione anteriormente me mencionas si te funciono en lo que reviso el stacktrace.

Comment: Si lo he revisado  y ahora el estatus de la conexion es 200, o sea logra conectarse pero el array que devuelve esta vacio {
    "options": []
} . Creo que de algun modo esta en el json, ya que no me trae los registros del modelo.

Comment: De acuerdo, ya no esta el error, solo que no regresa las opciones. Te sugiero que verifiques si te esta llegando el action del post con un print(request.POST.get('action', None))  para cerciorarte que llegue, y posteriormente ver que te trae el key 'term', agrega print(request.POST.get('term', None)) y verifica si te esta llegando el term. Me comentas si te llegan bien estos dos valores, dependiendo de esto es lo siguiente a hacer.

Comment: los devuelve correctamente, te confieso que ahora mismo no entiendo porque no los devuelve dentro del json

Comment: De acuerdo, como me comentas que te llegan bien el term y el action entonces lo restante es validar que tu filtro este devolviendo resultados acá: prods = Item.objects.filter() te recomiendo igual con un print para que valides que tu queryset no esta vacío, si es vacio entonces es correcto que no tengas resultados,  si no es vacío entonces tu loop for i in prods: debe de ejecutarse, ahi puedes probar que te devuelva el json con un print en i.toJSON() para que veas si te esta parseando a json el objeto y por ultimo imprimir hasta el ultimo items para ver si la lista es correcta y no vacía.

Comment: Logrado, gracias a tu ayuda. Un saludo cordial